# How can I accomplish this design using divs and CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can I accomplish the above using divs and CSS?

Comment: I must say that I liked the original title better. :)

Comment: You forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Why do you care if it is a homework problem? :P

Comment: Can someone be redundant and put the text of the image in the body of the question?

Answer (score 3):

The code below should do it. The image in my example is 80 by 80 pixels. I'm assuming a 2 pixel white border inside, and added a little padding on the green box on the left and right.

[image: Result]
<sub>(source: [subbot.net](http://www.subbot.net/personal/external/stackoverflow/css-happymyself.png))</sub>

(I mis-cropped a little, but you get the idea)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerBorder">
        <img src="images/thorarin.jpg" />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... (snip)
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    div.wrapper
    {
        border: solid 2px red;
    }

    div.wrapper div.innerBorder
    {
        border: solid 2px white;
        background-color: green;
        padding-right: 3px;
        height: 80px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }        

    div.wrapper div.innerBorder img 
    {
        float: left;
        border-right: solid 2px white;
        margin-right: 3px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
    }
</style>
```

**Edit:** oops, removed the clearing `DIV`. I originally made this for variable height, but that wasn't a requirement.

Comment: The overflow is optional, but otherwise +1